# Prevent touching corners (JS Game)

Tags: javascript

How can I prevent this map generator from creating touching corners like this:

```
-X
X-
```

Or

```
X-
-X
```

Here is a simplified example of the generator: http://jsfiddle.net/fDv9C/2/

Comment: @Gareth lots of things. This is a small scale simplified example of the problem at hand. I have tried post filtering to add and remove blocks when a corner is found, but can't get it quite right.

Comment: there is no javascript whatever in the jsfiddle! did you even give it a go?

Comment: @RachelGallen its all in the HTML tab. Did you use your scroll bar?

Comment: [This link](http://jsfiddle.net/fDv9C/1/) might be nicer for viewing and fiddling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question answers itself, almost.

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qBJVY/

```
if (!!grid[y][x] && !!grid[y+1][x+1] && !grid[y+1][x] && !grid[y][x+1]) {
    good=false;
    grid[y+1][x]=2;
}
```

It simply checks for the combinations you do not want and patches them up. It always adds a grid point so as not to disconnect any parts of the map.

This in turn may lead to another situation where the issue may occur, but if it changed anything (that is, if it found a problem), it will simply check again. This can be optimized, for instance by recursively adjusting whatever was changed, but usually it only needs 1 or 2 passes. There's a limiter on there to not allow more than 100 passes, just in case there is some unforeseen circumstance in which it cannot fix it (I can't think of such a situation, though :) ).

Comment: Thanks, this is the first answer that solved the question, although I have already sorted it. However you get the bounty. http://jsfiddle.net/fDv9C/19

Comment: Yay! I can now comment! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the way that you are creating board it's very difficulty to do this checking during generation. I create simple function that check board after. It's using flood algorithm. Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jzTEX/8/ (blue background is original map, red background is map after checking)

Basically we create second array `grid2`. After filling `grid` we run recursively `floodV` function

```
function floodV(x,y) {
    var shiftArray = [[0,1],[0,-1],[1,0],[-1,0]];
    grid2[y][x]=1;
    for(var k=0;k<4;k++) {
        var x1=x+shiftArray[k][0];
        var y1=y+shiftArray[k][1];
        if(grid[y1][x1] == 1 && grid2[y1][x1] == 0 && checkV(x1,y1)) {
            grid2[y1][x1] = 1;
            floodV(x1,y1);
        }
    }
}
```

with the check function

```
function checkV(x,y) {
    var checkVarr = [[-1,-1], [-1,1], [1,1], [1,-1]];
    for(var k=0;k<4;k++) {
        if(grid[y+checkVarr[k][0]][x+checkVarr[k][1]] == 1 && grid[y+checkVarr[k][0]][x] == 0 && grid[y][x+checkVarr[k][1]] == 0 && grid2[y+checkVarr[k][0]][x+checkVarr[k][1]] == 1) 
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

This isn't perfect because we can sometimes throw away big parts of the map but if we try to start adding new elements we have to check whole map again (in worths case).

Comment: Thanks works pretty well, although it falsely identified this case: http://www.dumpt.com/img/viewer.php?file=cmud3yfkzcq3iulg2vx0.png

Comment: I modify `check` function (fiddle link also updated), please test it now.

Comment: Still not quite right: http://www.dumpt.com/img/viewer.php?file=5m5mk0hyh6d4k56i7noo.png But I think I haved sorted it as per http://jsfiddle.net/fDv9C/19/

Comment: As I said, when I'm removing tiles this can happend. If you want I can change my code that it will be adding tiles but yours solution seems right (but not optimal).

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did: http://jsfiddle.net/fDv9C/13/

Where's the magic happening? Scroll down to lines 53 through 58:

```
var bottom = y_next + 1;
var left = x_next - 1;
var right = x_next + 1;
var top = y_next - 1;

if (grid[top][left] || grid[top][right] ||
    grid[bottom][left] || grid[bottom][right]) continue;
```

In short your touching corner points can only occur at the computed next position. Hence if any one of the four corner neighbors of the next position exists, you must compute another next position.

You may even decrement the counter `i` when this happens to get as many paths as possible (although it doesn't really make a big difference):

```
var bottom = y_next + 1;
var left = x_next - 1;
var right = x_next + 1;
var top = y_next - 1;

if (grid[top][left] || grid[top][right] ||
    grid[bottom][left] || grid[bottom][right]) {
    i--;
    continue;
}
```

See the demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/fDv9C/12/

**Edit:** I couldn't resist. I had to create an automatic map generator so that I needn't keep clicking run: http://jsfiddle.net/fDv9C/14/

Comment: On both fiddles I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '24' of undefined fiddle.jshell.net/fDv9C/6/show/:88
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'get' of null`

Comment: @Petah - That's weird. It works fine for me. Show me a screenshot of your error console, or try using a different browser. Which one are you using?

Comment: http://www.dumpt.com/img/viewer.php?file=ubn3mhu5q36wxsmcrz7x.png (chrome  24.0.1312.57). Also   http://jsfiddle.net/fDv9C/8/ seems to not error. But it removes the "rooms", so it only make corridors.

Comment: @Petah - The problem is that Firefox and Chrome always treat the variable `top` as the top `window` of the page instead of what we define it as. Hence I changed the name from `top` to `up` and now it works: http://jsfiddle.net/fDv9C/9/

Comment: @Petah - I modified the links in my answer to point to the working demos. Is this what you wanted?

Comment: That has resolved the errors, however it is still removing cells that are completely surrounded by other occupied cells.